# Django-tinymce + django-filebrowser-no-grapelli doesn'work

Tags: django, admin, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser

I am confused a bit. I have tried different ways and manuals, but nothing works for me.
What I use: django 1.5, django-page-cms, django-tinymce. I need filebrowser for tinymce for using in admin. I stopped at https://github.com/wardi/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli , becouse it looks simpliest in usage and i don't need Grapeeli, which needs for https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser. So I need:

- add 'filebrowser' in INSTALLED_APPS;
- add `(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),` to urls before admin
- change /templates/admin/index.html adding `{% include 'filebrowser/append.html' %}` before  `{% for app in app_list %}`

After doing those steps and correcting append.html (for django 1.5 - change url look), I receive error `Reverse for 'tinymce-filebrowser' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` when I want enter into the page, where tinymce (and filebrowser) are in usage. Google can't get me certain answer what I need to do.

So I am hope for your help. If anyone has worked with such libraries, can you tell me please, What I need to do in that case? Or is there another working filebrowser exists with the understanding configuration?

**UPDATE.** After adding tinymce urls and editing almoust all filebrowser templates (becouse of django 1.5). I have some problems:

- at the page with tinymce redactor I see in console error: `localhost:8000/admin/tinymce/filebrowser/ 404 (NOT FOUND)` . tinynce still works fine, but i can't use filebrowser's image-link, which appears after adding filebrowser (error in console: `Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` )
- uploading of files (directly, without tinymce) always fails here: `localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/upload_file/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Any ideas how to solve those problems?

**UPDATE.** For solving first problem you need put `(r'^admin/tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),`  before     `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`.

For solving second problem you need use right package of django-filebrowser-no-grapelli, preferably where no flash_login_decorator for upload function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not added django-tinymce urls in urls.py:

```
(r'^admin/tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
```